# How to support Xcode Templates for SwiftPM?

Tags: xcode, xcode-template, swiftpm

I have Xcode Template that generate a bunch of files (not project) with some predefined repetitive code (for example classes for MVVM pattern). When I try to create these files in Xcode Project all works fine (I can find and create my templates in `New File…` menu), but when I try to do the same thing in SwiftPM I can't find my templates in the `New File…` menu.

All my templates are leaving in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/**/*.xctemplate`.

What should I do to show templates for SwiftPM as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/` folder I found that some default templates have the property `SupportsSwiftPackage` that set to `YES`. I added it to my templates and it finally works.

[image]